# programmatically use w3c css/html validators with custom html

Tags: javascript, validation, web-crawler

#### *edit*

I've got it working for CSS, only HTML validation to go.

```
let css = Array.from(document.styleSheets)
        .reduce((combinedsheet,sheet) => sheet.rules? 
          combinedsheet + Array.from(sheet.rules)
            .reduce((p,c) => p+c.cssText+'\n', ''):
          combinedsheet, '')        
      try {
        document.querySelector('a.validation.css').href = 
          'https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?text=' +
          encodeURIComponent(css) +
          '&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning='

        document.querySelector('a.validation.html').href = 
          'https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=' +
          encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('html'))
      } catch (e) {
        // this will fail before page fully loads, and we can be silent about that
      }
```

#### edit #2

I've got it working. The only problem is that this uses a "popup" instead of opening a window silently like `target="blank"` would. I'm using an onlick method:

```
get_html_validation: function () {
    let fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('fragment', '<!DOCTYPE html>' + 
      document.querySelector('html').outerHTML)
    fd.append('prefill', 0)
    fd.append('doctype', 'Inline')
    fd.append('prefill_doctype', 'html401')
    fd.append('group', 0)

    axios.post("https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea", fd)
      .then(response => {
        let win=window.open('about:blank')
        console.log(win)
        with(win.document)
        {
          open()
          write(response.data)
          close()
        }
      })
      .catch(e => console.error(e))
  }
```

#### original

I'd like to use these validators programmatically:

- https://validator.w3.org/nu
- http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

— they work just fine if you pass a URL as a parameter, so long as the document doesn't have javascript that manipulates the dom. But... mine does.

How can I hand these sites custom html to check using javascript in the browser?  I'm looking to do something like:

```
onValidateDOM = () => {
  let toValidate = '<!DOCTYPE html>' + document.querySelector('html').outerHTML
  let returnURLs = []
  returnURLs.push(w3cCSS.validate(toValidate), w3cHTML.validate(toValidate)
  return returnURLs
}
```

Comment: @PatrickBarr did you mean to leave that comment somewhere else?

Comment: No, sorry I misinterpreted your question before the edit

Comment: nps, glad I edited it then :)

Comment: What about posting the data to them in the same way that their "Check by" `text input` works?

Comment: @gforce301 yeah so thats a great idea.. use FormData() to build the request and then easy to post it with for example axios. The only problem with that is that the callback / promise will contain the response, which makes it hard to link to the results. I need a link for an anchor tag

Comment: It looks like there's an [HTML Validator API](https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html) and a [CSS Validator API](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/api.html)

Comment: thanks patrick - looks like there's no GET method in my case..

Comment: For the case of https://validator.w3.org/nu you can make a GET request with an HTML string if you first construct a `data:` URL from the HTML and give that as the value of the `doc` query parameter; for example: `https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<!doctype html><title>test</title><p foobar>` https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%253C%2521doctype%2520html%253E%253Ctitle%253Etest%253C%252Ftitle%253E%253Cp%2520foobar%253E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `toValidate` passed to `encodeURIComponent()` as value to `doc=` query

```
fetch(`https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=${encodeURIComponent(toValidate)}`)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => console.log(text));
```

Comment: umm, unfortunately no. the `doc` parameter accepts the URL, not the html from the file

Comment: @robertotomás Apparently https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator is not served with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Though the following is possible at the domain `var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("text", "body {color: red;}");
fetch("https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator", {method:"POST", body:fd})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => console.log(text))` which should result with https://jsfiddle.net/6ujqempv/. You could try using `YQL` to make request

Comment: I notice that I _can_ use text= and pass in urlencoded CSS for the css validator. So one down! edit: adding actual code to post)